# Deleting Single character in LCD

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, serial, lcd

While I have successfully cleared all the lcd display with the help of some guys here by a cheat code (because it doesnt really delete the display)`for (int i=0; i < 80; i++)`, Now I needed to delete  **single character** on my lcd display.

*Note:*
I am using serial communication with my [lcd module](http://www.e-gizmo.com/KIT/images/eterm/E-term.pdf). I intensively search the internet but I could not find any solution, Is there anyone who had an Idea to do so?

Comment: Why do people always write/say "LCD display"? The D stands for display!

Comment: The e-Term actually consists of an LCD, a keypad and a microcontroller with a serial port. Whoever wrote the software for the microcontroller defined whatever display manipulations are going to be possible via the serial port. However, while the hardware manual is readily available, I can't find any hint of a software/protocol manual for the device. Good luck!

Comment: Wow, I actually went and looked at the thing. I almost regret having done so. I say "almost" because at least I don't have to *use* the thing. And I never will.

Comment: noting that this is a continuation of [clear my LCD](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21121659/how-can-i-clear-an-lcd-from-my-arduino/21122775#comment31783878_21122775) did @cup’s suggestion of sending “Serial.write(chr(2) + chr(12) + chr(3))” work? If so then you could use [Send_to()](https://gist.github.com/egizmocodes/7819592#file-seriallcd2-ino-L123) as it looks like it may be standard codes only surrounded by STX and ETX characters.

Comment: @Samuel - Presumably for the same reason people say "ATM Machine" and "RPMs"?

Comment: @mpflaga No, it didn't work.

Comment: not certain, but it looks like this may be the same LCD used by Parallax. May be a Devantech LCD03. Have you sent a support request to eGizmo for clarification and documentation

Answer (score 3):

With years of experience dealing with display devices I can tell you that the best general purpose strategy for dealing with the update of an LCD module is to keep a string buffer image in RAM of what is on the display. Have your software do any necessary manipulation and editing of the display content against the memory buffer image. Once the image is modified call a routine that homes the cursor on the display and copies the whole buffer out to the display in a sequential manner.

Answer (score 2):

The HD44870 command set has no provisions for deleting characters. You will need to read out all the following characters on the display, write them in the appropriate place, and then put one or more blank spaces after.

Comment: No option to move the cursor and write a space?

Comment: @IgnacioVasquez-Abrams Meaning I cant realy delete single character on my lcd?

Comment: @geometrikal: *Replacing* a character is easy. Deleting it is not.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams so how can I replace a character, maybe i can work it out.

Comment: You move to the location, and you output the character.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams will this work on a **serial lcd**? because as ive searched you will use `lcd.setCursor()` and this code only works on parallel communication.

Comment: It will work on anything you can read the datasheet for...

Comment: datasheet for what?

Comment: Uh... for the LCD.

Comment: IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - The OP is a bit confused because he doesn't actually have a LCD, he has a LCD with a Z86733 (yeah, Z80) MCU hung off it, with basically no documentation. @NewInEverything - You're going to need to contact the manufacturer, and ask them to *actually* document their product.

Comment: @NewInEverything - **You have a parallel LCD**, It just has a MCU between the serial port and the LCD. The datasheet you link does *not* have proper command description, and honestly, I think their website is going to give me ocular herpes, so I don't want to look at it any longer.

Comment: Note: Found the manual despite [websitebomination](http://www.e-gizmo.com/KIT/e-TERM.html). It's a link to a *google doc*, **and the link is broken**.

Comment: Yeah... I think he's better off desoldering the LCD module and using it directly.

Comment: @Ignacio: I did [suggest that](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/96484/2191) :-)